# thread_info returns MACH_SEND_INVALID_DEST instead of KERN_SUCCESS

Tags: ios, ios8, nsoperation, mach

A call to `thread_info` now returns [`MACH_SEND_INVALID_DEST`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1075/_index.html) instead of `KERN_SUCCESS` and I don't yet understand what has caused this new circumstance.

What could be the reason for this return value. I pass a valid obtained from `mach_thread_self()` when called inside an `NSOperation` as `thread_act_t` (i.e first parameter). At the time when the call to `thread_info()` is made the operation may have completed but its `NSOperationQueue` is still retained. Is it that `NSOperation` may have executed on a thread that no longer exists at the time of the call?

Basically I want to find out how long the operation took in terms of the thread's user and system time. The operation invokes an asynchronous service at its tail, `thread_info()` is called from that service's completion handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now `wait` for an `NSCondition` inside the `NSOperation` (after it invoked the asynchronous service, i.e. at its very end) and `signal` it in the completion handler. That seems to have resolved the issue.